# Solving a non homogeneous second order ode with constant coefficients and an arbitrary non homogeneous term

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Here is the equation$$ax''+bx'+cx=\phi(t)$$The unkown function is x(t). $\phi(t)$ is a known function, a,b,c are known constants. 

NOTE: Express the solution in terms of a, b, c, and $\phi(t)$.

Comment: Yeah, I know how to solve it when the RHS is specified. But the known function on the RHS is not specified, and you're required to express the solution in terms of that symbol

Comment: ok, i got it, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
$\ds{a{\rm x}''\pars{t} + b{\rm x}'\pars{t} + c{\rm x}\pars{t} = \phi\pars{t}:\
     {\large ?}}$

> Write $\ds{{\rm x}\pars{t}}$ as:
>   $$
> {\rm x}\pars{t} = A\varphi_{1}\pars{t} + B\varphi_{2}\pars{t}
> + \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\rm G}\pars{t,t'}\phi\pars{t'}\,\dd t'
> $$
>   where $\ds{\varphi_{j}\pars{t}}$ $\ds{\pars{j = 1, 2}}$ are independent solutions
>   of $\ds{a{\rm x}''\pars{t} + b{\rm x}'\pars{t} + c{\rm x}\pars{t} = 0}$.
>   $\ds{A}$ and $\ds{B}$ are constants such that
>   $\ds{A\varphi_{1}\pars{t} + B\varphi_{2}\pars{t}}$ satisfies the "*initial conditions*".

$\ds{{\rm G}\pars{t,t'}}$ satisfies:
$$
\begin{array}{l}
\pars{a\,\partiald[2]{}{t} + b\,\partiald{}{t} + c}{\rm G}\pars{t,t'} = 0\,,
\qquad t \not= t'
\\[3mm]
\left.a\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^{+}}\partiald{{\rm G}\pars{t,t'}}{t}
\right\vert_{t\ =\ t' - \epsilon}^{t\ =\ t' + \epsilon} = 1
\end{array}
$$
$\ds{{\rm G}\pars{t,t'}}$, as a function of $\ds{t}$, satisfies "*homogeneous initial conditions*" since $\ds{A\varphi_{1}\pars{t} + B\varphi_{2}\pars{t}}$
already "takes care" of the "*initial conditions*".

Comment: @FelixMartin Is this the result after you applied the method of "variation of parameter"?